# Unknown Function in Vim

Tags: vim

I have the following file (vimscript.vim):

```
function HelloWorld()
  echo "Hello World"
endfunction

call HelloWorld()
```

When I open that file and I type the following:

```
:call HelloWorld()
```

I get an error:

```
E117: Unknown function: HelloWorld
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to `source` the file first:

```
:source path/to/file/vimscript.vim
```

Alternatively, you can put the function in your vimrc instead, which is typically located at `~/.vimrc`, so that it's defined every time you open Vim.

Or, you could use a combination of both, and put

```
source path/to/file/vimscript.vim
```

in your `.vimrc`.